# Complex conjugate to the power proof.

Tags: complex-numbers

How can I proof that:
$$(z^n)^* = (z^*)^n$$

Where: 
z is a complex number,
n is a positive whole number
* is the complex conjugate

Comment: Do you know how to prove that $(zw)^*=z^*w^*$? if so, just use induction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Write $z = re^{i\theta}$, then $\overline{z} = re^{-i\theta}$. So
$$
\overline{z}^n = r^n e^{-in\theta} = \overline{r^ne^{in\theta}} = \overline{z^n}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Use induction. First check it for $n=2$:
$$
(z^{\ast})^{2} = (a - ib)^{2} = a^{2} - 2i ab - b^{2} = (a^{2} + 2i ab - b^{2})^{\ast} = (z^{2})^{\ast}
$$
Now, show that if it's true for every natural up to a certain $n$, then it's true for $n+1$.

Comment: What do you plan to do with (z^2.z)* without assuming that it's equal to (z^2)*.z* (which is the behaviour that we're trying to prove.)

Comment: Alternatively, if you're happy to assume (zw)* = z*w*, then you don't need a complicated first step for n=2

Answer (score -1):

For the next step in the proof by induction. Show that $x^*y^*=(xy)^*$ for all complex numbers.  That allows you to then show that if $(x^*)^2=(x^2)^*$  then $(x^*)^2 \cdot x^* = (x^3)^*$, and so on.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).